# Generating html files in a console application

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, templates, template-engine

I need to get data from a database and I need to spit out this data in html formatk using my command line app. For this I am planning to use some sort of template-engine. I was wondering if there is anything in .NET that can do this for me?

The best option would be if I could reuse the asp.net mvc template engine (razor) in my app, this way I should not need to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use Razor outside ASP.Net, the current release is somewhat crippled, so you have to use [some hacks](http://blog.andrewnurse.net/2010/07/22/UsingTheRazorParserOutsideOfASPNet.aspx), but it will be simplified in the final release.

Comment: The hyperlink has a good resource. The author of the blog is on the team that is writing the Razor parser.

Comment: If you like an answer, then upvote it. If you have an addition to an answer then edit it. Collaborative websites ftw :-)